Bumping when cornering in my Kia Sportage
I recently went through a large pothole in my 2015 Kia Sportage which caused damage to the front passenger-side alloy wheel and the tyre.
Shortly afterwards, I noticed a bumping when cornering at low-speed, especially when pulling a tight right-turn at T-junctions or roundabouts. I assumed that this must also be coming from the front passenger side (British right-hand drive car), but now, after several weeks I think it is from the back passenger side.
I did have it briefly examined by a mechanic, who found nothing (possibly because I was talking about damage to the front of the car), but now I think the problem is becoming more obvious and pronounced.
Before I submit the vehicle for further examination, does anybody have any ideas on this one?
